# Rearrange words to make a sentence

Tags: mathematics, geometry

The following puzzle is from the October 1961 issue of the Eureka journal (published by The Cambridge University Mathematical Society):

**Rearrange the order of the following so as to make a true statement:**

*angles are degrees has less more no not seventy than than triangle two which*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> no triangle has more than two angles which are not less than seventy degrees

A confusing string of negatives. To put it another way,

> A triangle cannot have three angles which all measure seventy degrees or more.

Answer (score 15):

Another take:

> no triangle has more than seventy angles which are not less than two degrees

This is true since

> A triangle only has three angles, and thus cannot have more than 70 angles, including those which are 2 degrees or more.

Comment: +1 Very imaginative!

Answer (score 8):

Yet another solution:

> No triangle has angles which are more than, not less than, two seventy degrees.

In other words:

> You can't have an angle of more than $270^\circ$ in a triangle. Even $180^\circ$ is too big. (For emphasis, we clarify that we are talking about angles more than $270^\circ$, not less than $270^\circ$.)

Comment: +1 Wow!  So many correct answers; I mistakenly thought there was only one solution.